# After compiling a simple C++ code in eclipse, it doesn't show the problems as described in my instruction

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, mingw

I am learning C++ along with a script. Eclipse is my IDE and I'm using MinGW64 as a compiler.
In the script there is following code written, which I am just supposed to copy and compile first:

[Supposed code from script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vekON.png)

My script says that as soon as I compile it, in the lower window under "Problems" there should be shown "0 times" and under "Console" there's supposed to be shown:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld **** 
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
g++ -o HelloWorld.exe main.o
Build Finished
```

But instead, when I compile the same code (that's my code):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    int max;
    max = 10;

    for (int var = 0; var < max; ++var)
    {
        std::cout << var << std:endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get following notifications under "Problems" and "Console":
[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XanJi.png)
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRckm.png)

I'm definetly compiling on MinGW GCC but I don't know the reason why my Problem and Console notifications are differing from the script, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two problems.

The easy one. On line 12 you have a typo. It should say `std::endl;` rather than `std:endl;` You are missing a colon, it's just that.

The harder one. When I load the following code into Visual Studio on Windows, it compiles and runs correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    int max;
    max = 10;

    for (int var = 0; var < max; ++var)
    {
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So the problem is your setup. My guess is that your include folder hasn't been set up properly. You need to tell the compiler where to look for iostream.

My gcc is at  C:\tools\msys64\mingw64. The include folder is directly below this. Try `which gcc` on Linux or `get-command gcc` on Windows to locate your gcc system.

If you are on Windows, and you have enough memory in your computer you should consider Visual Studio. It's all in one really nice package, and it has a free version.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Indeed the program couldn't include <iostream> but after I rightclicked my folder on the left and selected "Build Project" instead of just clicking the hammer, it created a "Debug" folder and a "Binaries" section. After that I could build and run it without any problems.
Also I had to click "Build Project" several times until it worked, but anyways thanks!